# WPF Textual Separator for different inehriting objects in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, inheritance

Let's say i have an interface called IFoo

**IFoo.cs**

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

And this interface is inherited by two classes:

**GoodFoo.cs**

```
public class GoodFoo : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**BadFoo.cs**

```
public class BadFoo : IFoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's admit i have a class named FooConsumer

**FooConsumer.cs**

```
public class FooConsumer
{
    public IFoo MyFoo { get; set; }
}
```

So far everything looks quite standard, and you should be guessing what's coming next.

What I want to achieve is to get a collection of IFoo's containing GoodFoo's and BadFoo's (the easy part) and display them in a **single** ListView from which my FooConsumer will select it's IFoo.

My problem is to show them in a single ListView with this kind of template, alowing my user to select only one IFoo from this list wether it is a GoodFoo or a BadFoo :

> Foos
>
> **Good Foos :**
>
> -GoodFoo1
>
> -GoodFoo2
>
> -GoodFoo3
>
> ```
> ...etc
> ```
>
> **Bad Foos :**
>
> -BadFoo1
>
> -BadFoo2
>
> -BadFoo3
>
> ```
> ...etc
> ```

I'm currently doing this in a mvvm project. 
I'm not sure that a ListView would be the best suited control for this problem. I believe I could achieve this with some StackPanels within a ScrollViewer (yet I'm not sure how I would handle the SelectedItem), but there must be a better way.

Comment: Have you tried with a grouping of GoodFoo and BadFoo? If not, refer to this link: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/

Comment: Looks like this answers my problem. I'll keep you informed if I succed or meet any trouble. 
Feel free to post this as answer so i could validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with a grouping of GoodFoo and BadFoo? If not, Give it a try: 
[This](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/) can be good starting point to understand grouping in ListView

Let me know if you need any more help on this.